# ArcObjects 10/10.1 Get rid of Invalid layer symbol in TOC

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, feature-layer

I've written an add-in (VS2010, C#) that finds specific invalid feature layers in ArcMap and fixes them.  After the layer is fixed, the red invalid symbol still appears in the TOC.  An activeview.refresh doesn't take care of it.  How does one programatically get that layer entry to appear as valid without manual intervention?

Comment: What about ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IContentsView::Refresh(null)?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just need to refresh the Table of Contents.  Try something like this:

```
IMxDocument pDoc = (IMxDocument)pApp.Document;

for (int i = 0; i < pDoc.ContentsViewCount; i++)
{
     pDoc.ContentsView[i].Refresh(null);
}
```

Comment: That does the trick.  I tried to upvote your answer, but apparently I don't have the minimal number of points yet for it to be accepted.